# Navigation bar back button change functionality

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, navigationbar

I have 3 view controllers: A, B and C. A is initial and it has 2 buttons: one is redirecting to B, and second one to C. When B is pushed, and button within B pressed user is redirected to C. Now on navigation bar within C, when I press back button I want to be redirected to A always, and never to B. Is that possible?

This is base functionality I want to achieve:

a)

```
A->B->C      C back to A
```

b)

```
A->C         C back to A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[A class]])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                              animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is answer I needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is replacing the back button by a custom button.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Show how to do it, provide a sample, a method to use?

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this with presentview controller as modal view.first from a if first button is pressed present b view.if secnd button is pressed present c view and in c view controller put back button and add delegates and implement the delegate in a view controller.and you will have to dismiss one view after the other in a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

After reading what you said I think you meant implementing custom actions for each button.The way I would do it(In Swift) is this:

```
@IBAction func pressButton(sender : UIButton){

 var SecondView :ViewController2
 SecondView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondView") as ViewController2
 self.presentViewController(SecondView, animated: true, completion:nil)
 self.viewWillDisappear(true)
}
```

This method I have used a lot and I know there is another way using segues but you still use @IBActions.You just create a new segue(identifier) and in the `prepareforSegue` method you say what happens when that segue is triggered